# Populating a simple UITableView in MonoTouch with UITableViewDataSource - how to use UITableViewDataSource

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I'm loving MonoTouch so far, but find the documentation and samples lacking once you get past the few beginner lessons.

I am struggling with a simple concept of populating a simple UITableView in MonoTouch.  I have seen examples of doing this with custom cells, and extensively customizing the list with varying pieces of information, but I am just looking for the bare minimum of how to achieve this simple thing.  I'm a professional .NET developer and very new to iOS, so still wrapping my head around how it works.

I just want the following.
Create a list of items
Assign that list of items to the UITableView to allow the user to scroll the list.  Looking for a very very simple example.

The biggest thing I am struggling with is creating a UITableViewDataSource object.  It's abstract so I can't create an instance of it.  I could create my own class that inherits it, but I am looking for a concrete implementation in the framework to use without having to create my own.  Am I too spoiled by .NET and have to create a new class for it, or does it exist somewhere in the Framework and I just can't find it?

**[Answer here]**
I found an answer, but StackOverflow won't let me answer my own question with less than 100 reputation or unless I wait 8 hours which I am not willing to do.  Answer below:

I created the following class that inherits UITableViewSource.  It is a requirement to do it this way.  GetCell controls how you will render the cell on the table.

Create an instance of this and pass in a list of strings to populate.

This example came from (I modified it slightly) the book I am reading from Wrox Press - "Professional iPhone Programming with MonoTouch and .NET C#"

```
public class TableViewSource : UITableViewSource
{
    private List<string> rows;

    public TableViewSource (List<string> list) 
    { 
            rows = list; 
    }

    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section) 
    { 
        return rows.Count; 
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {  
        UITableViewCell cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default,"mycell"); 
        cell.TextLabel.Text = rows[indexPath.Row];
        return cell;
    } 
}
```

Put the following code in ViewDidLoad on your screen.

```
var list = new List<String>()
{   
    "San Francisco",    
    "Buenos Aires", 
    "São Paulo"
};

TableViewSource tableData = new TableViewSource(list);
this.tblTrips.Source = tableData;
```

This gives me what I am looking for without requiring a deep dive into MonoTouch.Dialog

Answer (score 2):

`UITableView`, and associated delegate and datasource types, is not a very friendly API - even less for the typical .NET developer. There are times when it's needed but, in most cases, you'll want to use something simpler.

> Create a list of items Assign that list of items to the UITableView to allow the user to scroll the list. Looking for a very very simple example.

That seems to fit [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog)'s goal. The assembly is now shipped with MonoTouch but you can find the [sample source code](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/tree/master/Sample) on github.

Xamarin's documentation web site also has a [tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/MonoTouch.Dialog) for using MonoTouch.Dialog and a nice [video](http://g.xamarin.com/2012/02/10/easily-create-ios-user-interfaces-with-monotouch-dialog/) is also available.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, and I will potentially look into this in the future.  But, to be fair, I was looking for how to use the existing objects within mono and I found an example that let's me do that in a book I am reading.  See my answer below.  Now that I understand how it works and how to use GetCell to render the cell and that it is required to create my own implementation of UITableViewSource, I think I am well on my way to understanding this.

Comment: MT.Dialog is a great tool, but I agree that you really need to understand how to use TableViews natively - they're a pretty core part of iOS UI.  I'm surprised Xamarin doesn't have a good sample of doing this in their doc library.

Comment: Since I can't answer my own question with less than 100 reputation this question will go unanswered.  It's too bad as my answer would genuinely help the community.  I will have forgotten to answer it in 8 hours when I am eligible to do so according to StackOverflow rules.  [I strongly disagree with this rule] - I will post the answer as part of the question to work around this...

Comment: I will check out MT.Dialog later.  Right now just learning core concepts of MT and iOS development/CocoaTouch.

Comment: @Jason I totally agree :) but it's easier to learn to walk before learning to run. AFAIK there's no tutorial but there's a few recipes about them http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/recipes/Content_Controls/Tables